# How to fix split property, to give not undefined

Tags: javascript

I need to have the right function to test, which is giving me string from a fullName and which I have to split and using for loop change the letters to a char "*". I want to keep the first upperCase visible: here is my code:

```
var fullName = "Jozko Baci";
function testSamoUloha(fullName) {
    var splitString=fullName.split("");
    for (var i=1;i<splitString[1].length;i++) {
        splitString[1].replace(splitString[1][i],"*");
    }
    var anonymName =splitString[0]+" "+splitString[1];
    console.log(anonymName);
    }
testSamoUloha();
```

I'm really new to it, this problem took me two hours to have at least some solution.

I expect that from the string above will become string saved in variable anonymName as "Jozko B***";

Comment: Note: `testSamoUloha` expects a `fullname` argument but you don't provide one: `testSamoUloha();` should be `testSamoUloha(fullName);`

Comment: Also, what's the criteria for turning the letters to an asterisk?

Comment: I'm sorry what is asterisk?

Comment: This is an asterisk: `*`

Comment: I hoped only criteria I need is for loop, or what do you mean?

Comment: I have tried in for loop starts at index[1] from already splitted string into two parts until length of the string and then commit it again together to a new anonym variable, is that okey?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex if you'd like to make your code shorter:

```
(?<=^.+\s\S+)\w
```

it will match any letter `\w` that is preceded `(?<=` by start of string `^`, any number of chars `.+`, a whitespace `\s` and one or more non-whitespace characters `\S+`

```js
const fullName = "Jozko Baci";

const censored = fullName.replace(/(?<=^.+\s\S+)\w/g, '*');
console.log(censored);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do it with something like this;

```js
const fullName = "Jozko Baci";

// Break name into words (firstName, lastName)
let res = fullName.split(' ').map((word, wordIndex) =>
    // If after firstName
    wordIndex > 0
        // Hide all but first character in word
        ? word.split('').map((char, charIndex) => (charIndex > 0 ? '*' : char)).join('')
        // Else, show entire word
        : word
).join(' '); // Join words back together (firstName, lastName)
console.log(res);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I havent completely understood that function in return.
What does do e doing there and where it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

The above code looks fine, just added a fix in this line

> splitString[1].replace(splitString[1][i],"*")

Also added fix to `var splitString=fullName.split(" ");`
replaced

```
fullName.split("");  // ['J', 'o', 'z', 'k', 'o',  ' ', 'B', 'a', 'c', 'i']
```

with

```
fullName.split(" "); // ['Jozko', 'Baci']
```

> if you use replace on a string it returns the new string after replace
>   , its is not rewriting the existing string

for eg:

```
var a = "hello";
a.replace('o', '*') // returns hell*
a // has hello
```

but if you do

```
a = a.replace('o', '*') // returns hell* and rewrites a
a // hell*
```

similarly after adding this fix the existing code works fine

```js
 var fullName = "Jozko Baci";
    function testSamoUloha(fullName) {
        var splitString=fullName.split(" ");
        for (var i=1;i<splitString[1].length;i++) {
            splitString[1] = splitString[1].replace(splitString[1][i],"*");
        }
        var anonymName =splitString[0]+" "+splitString[1];
        console.log(anonymName);
        }
    testSamoUloha(fullName);
```

Comment: Oh yeah I get it and it helped to me a lot, thanks a lot.

Comment: Let me know if this fix resolves your issue.., If yes do upvote and accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable (you can't change them) so this code:

```
splitString[1].replace(splitString[1][i],"*");
```

won't work in any situation.

What I suggest is you create a temporary string, then loop over the whole of your second word. If the index of the loop is 0 add the letter to the temporary string, otherwise add a `*`:

```js
var fullName = "Jozko Baci";

function testSamoUloha(fullName) {
  var splitString = fullName.split(' ');

  // Create a temporary string
  var tempString = '';

  // Loop over the whole second word
  for (var i = 0; i < splitString[1].length; i++) {

    // If the index is greater than zero (not the first letter)
    // add a * to the temporary string
    if (i > 0) {
      tempString += '*';

    // otherwise, if the index is 0, add the letter
    // to the temporary string instead
    } else {
      tempString += splitString[1][i];
    }
  }

  // Return your string from your function
  return splitString[0] + ' ' + tempString;
}

// Make sure you pass in the fullName as an argument
console.log(testSamoUloha(fullName));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, understandable and grateful for your help!

Comment: No problem, @RejzozroutkoTezbir. Apologies for the confusion earlier. & welcome to Stackoverflow.